# How can I have a menu that has a constant anchor or title, that has menu children that are of the same width as the anchor or title?

Tags: flutter, mobile, widget

I want to create a menu that has a static menu anchor that when clicked on, reveals menu options under it. The DropdownButton widget doesn't appeal to me because it doesn't have a menu anchor and the label of the menu is replaced by the selected option. I have tried using the MenuAnchor class but I now see that it doesn't seem possible to create the menu children of the same width as the MenuAnchor label. How can I be able to achieve this desired look and behavior?

The included screenshot is more or less what I am looking for.

[image: Example menu picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [PopupMenuButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html) widget. It accepts a child widget, which you can size and style any way you like. You can also pass child to each PopupMenuItem - you can set the same width on menu items as on the button itself.

Comment: @AndreiVoglin I just added an example picture to the question. Don't think this look can be achieved with PopupMenuButton.

Comment: Of course you can. You have complete control over all 'child' widgets, so you can make them look exactly the way you like it. And the widgets in your screenshot are fairly simple.

Comment: Gotcha. I understand now. Would I change the position and offset properties of the PopupMenuButton widget to get the menu options to display directly under the child widget?

Comment: Yes, you may need to set position: PopupMenuPosition.under. You may also need to set an offset property depending on how you style you widgets.

Comment: Use MenuAnchor.